# iOS In-App-Purchases auto-renewing subscription incorrect display on Manage Subscription page

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I am building an iOS app with In-App-Purchases (subscription based) and I am facing the issue when my app subscription manager appearance is different from the one that apple provides in their documentation.
We can see that 1. app name, 2. subscription group display name are missing despite the fact I have entered this information on appstoreconnect.com.

I wonder how can I fix it?

Note:

1. App is not released yet, so neither application nor in-app-purchase have been reviewed. However, I know that even when app gets distributed - this issue would not get solved.
2. All of the entered information is being saved.

[Actual problem on screenshot](https://prnt.sc/11ozb11)

[appstoreconnect.com subscription group settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nziin.png)

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you've shared the same image twice.

Comment: @romainsalles thanks, fixed first screenshot =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update:

Problem got solved when app became available on the App Store.